# Dynamically generated div InnerHtml rendering very different than when statically coded

Tags: c#, css, html, innerhtml

I have the following html markup in a form with with and UpdatePanel. This code is rendering/displaying exactly as I want when statically coded. However, when I use a while loop in the c# codebehind to dynamically concatenate the code for all the 'docbox' elements into a string then set that string into InnerHtml for div 'bookshelf_items', it renders/displays very differently. It appears that after the first .docbox div is generated, the subsequent docbox divs are inside it. Another bizarre thing is that everything that should display after 'bookshelf_items' disappears.

### Edit

```
 <div class="bookshelf_items" id="bookshelf_items" runat="server">

                    <div class='docbox'>
                        <div class='doc' contenteditable='true' id='doc_50'>
                            <div class='doc_title'>TEST TITLE</div>
                            <div class='doc_txt'>TEST TEXT</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='doc_date'>TEST DATE</div>
                        <div class='doc_del' ID='del_50' runat='server'  />
                        <div class='doc_getlyt' ID='getlyt_50' runat='server' />
                    </div>

  </div>
```

**Edit - removed the CSS
Edit - removed the C# codebehind**

Comment: Please narrow the problem down. Make the code as small as possible while it still prodeces the issue. Maybe you will find the cause and a solution by the way.

Comment: I have done the same thing with between 1 and 4 'docbox' div elements with same result. I have also replaced the dynamically inserted variables with a very simple "xxyy" string just in case there was something going on inside the dynamic content from the db and same results. I continue to actively troubleshoot while awaiting help.

Comment: If you are able to make your code smaller/simpler still getting the same issue, update the post, so it's more easier for others to analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        private void GetUserDocs(string user_id)
        {

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, title, alias, dt from dbo.user_works WHERE user_id = @user_id", connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user_id", user_id);
                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    // Check if the reader has any rows at all before starting to read.
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        string doclist_html = "<div class=\"bookshelf_items\" id=\"bookshelf_items\" runat=\"server\">";
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string doc_id = reader["id"].ToString().Trim();
                            string title = reader["title"].ToString().Trim();
                            string alias = reader["alias"].ToString().Trim();
                            string dt = reader["dt"].ToString().Trim();
                            string date = DateTime.Parse(dt).ToShortDateString();

                            //build doc html
                            doclist_html = doclist_html + String.Format(
                                     "<div class='docbox'>" +
                                        "<div class='doc' contenteditable='true' id='doc_x{0}'>" +
                                                "<div class='doc_title'>{1}" +
                                                "</div>" +
                                                "<div class='doc_txt'>{2}" +
                                                "</div>" +
                                        "</div>" +
                                        "<div class='doc_date'>{3}</div>" +
                                            "<div class='doc_del' ID='del_{0}' runat='server'  />" +
                                            "<div class='doc_getlyt' ID='getlyt_{0}' runat='server' />" +
                                    "</div>",
                                    doc_id, title, alias, date);


                        }
                        doclist_html += "</div>";
                        bookshelf_items.InnerHtml = doclist_html;


                        string testhtml = bookshelf_items.InnerHtml;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //username not found
                        lbl_error.Text = ">>Failed to get documents<<";

                    }
                }
            }
        }​
```

Comment: That almost seemed to help when I had one member to the set in that it brought back everything that followed 'bookshelf_items' but the member itself still looked broken, however I added a second record to the db and it broke the whole thing again. Do you mind if I ask your thinking on this one?

Comment: Try adding following : cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;  The default is 30 seconds and with a fragmented SQL Express database is can talk longer than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to my own problem and I want to post the answer here in case anyone else runs into the same issue

When setting the InnerHtml into my div, the following code broke the parent/child hierarchy

```
<div class='doc_del' ID='del_54 runat='server' />
<div class='doc_getlyt' ID='getlyt_54' runat='server' />
```

The solution was to replace the embedded close characters with specific div close tag as follows:

```
<div class='doc_del' ID='del_54 runat='server'></div>
<div class='doc_getlyt' ID='getlyt_54' runat='server'></div>
```

Hopefully this will save someone some time and frustration. I don't know why it works this way. Maybe someone who knows will share. Thanks to those who commented on my issue